# unique combination (using WorksheetFunction.Unique)

Tags: excel, vba, unique, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get a list of unique combinations, taking the first two characters from column A and concatenating it from column B:

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| aa-jhg | alfa |
| aa-khj | beta |
| ab-ztu | alfa |
| aa-ztu | alfa |

Result: [**aa-alfa**, **aa-beta**, **ab-alfa**]

The operation needs to be fairly quick, as I am looping through a large dataset and the operations is repeated a couple times, that's why I thought using `WorksheetFunction.Unique` would be a good idea, as I use it for a similar function that returns the unique items in a given column of a dataset (like this: `listUnique = WorksheetFunction.Unique(WorksheetFunction.Index(ds, 0, col))`).

For the concatenation of these two columns, the Excel formula that does this is:
`"=UNIQUE(LEFT(C[-19], 2)&""##""&C[-4])"` which I can't use because the worksheet is already closed at that point in my macro. Anyway, for the sake of it, I tried `Application.Evaluate("=UNIQUE(LEFT(C[-19], 2)&""##""&C[-4])")` and it also didn't work.

**Here's my (non-working) attemp** so far:

```
' listUniqueCombination()
' ds: Variant dataset (2 dimensions)
' col1/col2: the column numbers in the dataset to evaluate (i.e. columns 1 and 19)
' numChars: takes the first "numChars" characters from the left in col1

Function listUniqueCombination(ds As Variant, ByVal col1 As Variant, ByVal col2 As Variant, Optional numChars = 999) As Variant

  '... Deleted the unnecesary stuff for clarity

   listUniqueCombination = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Left(WorksheetFunction.Index(ds, 0, col1), numChars) & "##" & WorksheetFunction.Index(ds, 0, col2)) ' Error 2015
   
End Function
```

Can any of you give me a hint on how to fix that function?
It is not strictly necessary to use WorksheetFunction.Unique but it really needs to be lightning fast for datasets of about 600k rows.

Thank you everybody!

Comment: Use a dictionary and loop through the array. `Left` won't work on an array of values.

Comment: @Rory I was trying to avoid looping through the dataset, due to its size.

Comment: Have you actually timed it? I don't see much option at this point - might have been easier to populate an array directly from the sheet with the required characters.